# Change Visual Studio 2015 Find options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, find

Is there a way to change VS 2015 find options ?

Whenever I open a project, and try to find something, by default the find location is set to <kbd>Entire solution</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Current document</kbd>

In visual studio 2010/12/13 this is set to `Current document` by default.

Can this be modified in VS 2015 ?

Comment: That's odd. I use CTRL+SHIFT+F if I want to search the entire solution or CTRL+F if I want to search the current document. Do these work the same for you?

Comment: No, if I use CTRL + F, `Entire solution` is selected by default

Answer (score 0):

You should install the [SmartFind](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/015611c4-b357-4672-8977-f3ec92f0b808) extension. I wrote it because I had the same problem.

Source is here: https://github.com/laktak/vs-smartfind